# How to detect a string of data from xml in Xquery

Tags: sql-server-2005, xquery

I have an untyped XML column in Sql Server Database which holds values such as

```
 1
 <root><a>123</a></root>
 <root>23d</root>
 23
```

I was trying with the following query

```
declare @x xml
set @x='1'
select @x.exist('xs:int(.)')
```

But here the problem is exist function will return 1 even if `@x='<root><a>12</a></root>'`

I would like the output to '0' in such cases.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .exist() method returns 1 if the XQuery expression evaluates to non-null node list, otherwise it returns 0. So it'll return 1 every time in your example.

If I understand you correctly, you want it to return 1 when the value is just an integer, and 0 when it's XML?

In that case you need to do the following:

```
declare @x xml
set @x='<root><a>12</a></root>'
select ISNUMERIC(CAST(@x.query('/') AS nvarchar))
```

This should return 0

```
declare @x xml
set @x='12'
select ISNUMERIC(CAST(@x.query('/') AS nvarchar))
```

This should return 1

Comment: wow that works..i was thinking in the wrong direction.
Thanks PaddedCell.

Comment: Yeah PadddedCell. Awesome solutionz. Really helped me out :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about the built-in type test in XQuery?

```
. instance of xs:integer
```

Will give you a boolean true if the context item is an integer, false otherwise.

Comment: declare @x xml
set @x='1'
select @x.query('. instance of xs:integer')
The query above is giving me 'false'. Is this the way it's supposed to be used?

Comment: No idea how to glue this together with SQL/XML syntax. In theory, I think yes.